# ios - Architecture error with GData on XCode 6.1.1

Tags: ios, architecture, xcode6, x86-64, gdata

I have a project be written by XCode 6.1.1, iOS target is 7.0 and later. I would like to use GData API to get photo from Picasa. I have done integrating GData into my source code. I wrote some simple code to get ALBUM and PHOTO from it. Code like below:

```
- (GDataServiceGooglePhotos*)photoService {
      static GDataServiceGooglePhotos* service = nil;
      if (!service) {
          service = [[GDataServiceGooglePhotos alloc] init];
          [service setServiceShouldFollowNextLinks:YES];
      }
      [service setUserCredentialsWithUsername:@"username_here"
                                     password:@"password_here"];
      return service;
  }
- (void)loadGooglePhotos {
      NSLog(@"In fetchAllPhotos");
      GDataServiceGooglePhotos *service = [self photoService];
      GDataServiceTicket *ticket;
  }
```

I tried to build real devices (iPhone 5S - iOS 8.1) and get error:

```
 built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Users/it/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FkProject-eulqqeuaxggnvqardcrbmptkwxhn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGDataTouchStaticLib.a
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataServiceGooglePhotos", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
      "_kGDataGooglePhotosKindAlbum", referenced from:
          -[ViewController fetchAllPhotos] in ViewController.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Please give me a solution to fix this error!

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it myself. I just go to GData project and change Architecture in Build Setting to *$(ARCHS_STANDARD)*. Everything is OK now. I hope this experience will be helpful for someone.

Thanks all.
Ryan